# Can intensifiers intensify nouns?

Tags: nouns, pronouns, modifiers, intensifying-adverbs

So from what I've gathered intensifiers intensify either adjectives (modifiers) or adverbs (or adverbial phrases) but can they intensify nouns? eg.

"A long time ago your **heroic** grandfathers helped build the city council"

In this declarative sentence if 'heroic' is an intensifier, then isn't it intensifying the noun? As there is a personal pronoun 'your' before heroic and grandfathers. Or is it just not an intensifier completely?

Comment: Intensifiers are adverbs; "heroic" is an adjective.

Comment: A person can be a 'relative stranger' (someone you've rarely met) or a 'complete stranger' (someone you've never met) or 'a bit of a stranger' (someone you don't meet all that often) (etc). So there are degrees of 'strangerliness'. But a person can't be a 'total or 'absolute grandfather'. There aren't degrees of 'grandfatherness'. A 'heroic grandfather' is a grandfather who's heroic. 'Heroic' here tells us he's both a grandfather and a hero, not that he's more grandfathery.

Comment: You're confusing the semanto-syntactic notion of intensification (very red, very old, very angry, very heroic, very evil, utterly depraved ...) with bigging someone up (a marvellous person, a heroic character, a wonderful grandfather).

Comment: My advice to you is to ditch the term 'intensifier' and stick with the traditional term 'degree modifier'. In any case, the term 'intensifier' applies to adverbs, not adjectives, and "heroic" belongs to the latter category -- so it wouldn't qualify as either an intensifier or a degree modifier.

Answer (score 1):

'Heroic' is an adjective here.

It does not 'intensify' the meaning of 'grandfather'.

It just describes an aspect of the grandfathers.

There is no way of 'intensifying' the concept 'grandfather', as such.

Adverbs apply a meaning to a verb which is qualitative. This quality can then be enhanced. But nouns are things. They are what they are.

Answer (score 0):

In the [British Council Article on Intensifiers](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/adjectives/intensifiers), after the regulation treatment of modifiers-of-adjectives

eg extremely cold / piping hot / finger-lickin' good

and modifiers-of-adverbs

eg very quickly / desperately slowly

there is a relevant section:

> **Adjectives as intensifiers:**
>
> We use some adjectives as intensifiers with nouns:
>
> absolute  total   complete  utter     perfect     real
>
> We say:
>
> *He’s a complete idiot*.
>
> *They were talking utter nonsense*.
>
> [*It was a total fiasco*.
>
> *She's a perfect stranger*.
>
> *He's a real sweetie*.
>
> *It was an absolute nightmare*.]

[A similar phrase is used in *It's a lead-pipe cinch.*]

Though some would reserve the term 'intensifier' (as with 'downtoner') for those words  modifying adjectives and adverbs.

.......

Of course, it only makes sense to add intensification to certain nouns. 'Grandfather' is not one of these. There may be different levels of idiocy, but a grandfather is a grandfather.